# Keep a UIView or UIViewController on top of all others

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

I am subclassing UIApplication to intercept and display touches in my TouchDisplay view. I would like to extend the Application, Window, Delegate or Main ViewController in order to keep my TouchDisplay view on top of all other views. As my and most other applications work, views and controllers are added and removed all the time. I figure the correct answer will be able to deal with these additions and removals and stil keep the TouchDisplay view on top.

Thanks for your help,
Joe

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but UIView has methods like `[self.view insertSubview:view below/aboveView:anotherView];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few approaches you could take for this:

1. If you're targeting *iOS 5+ and iPad only*, you can make a top-level view controller which has two contained view controllers. The first would be a view controller for your "TouchDisplay" view. The second would be the application's normal root view controller. (i.e. your existing main view controller; you'll need to set *definesPresentationContext* to YES on this view controller) Since you're writing the container view controller, you can order those two subviews however you like. There is a [WWDC 2011 Talk on view controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) that goes into great detail about this. This is the most "correct" approach IMHO, because it gives you a view controller for your TouchDisplay view, handles rotation and generally plays nice with others. (This only works on iPad, because on iPhone a new modal view always covers the full screen.)
2. A more straight-forward approach is to simply add your TouchView to your existing top-level UIWindow as a subview with `addSubview:`. Most applications don't actually remove the top-level view controller or add new top-level ones; they just present other view controllers from it. A view you add in the top-level window will stay above those. Of course, your app may not follow this rule, in which case you might try option #3 instead. This has rotation gotchas (your view will not auto-rotate when the device rotates, so you need to do this yourself.) You could also force your view back to top, say, on a 1-second timer, if you are having issues with other things covering it. This is also not as nice as option #1 because you don't get a UIViewController, just a UIView.
3. The most extreme approach is that you can create another UIWindow and give it a higher window level, such as `UIWindowLevelAlert` and put your TouchDisplay view in that. You can then make the window background transparent, and it will stay above your normal app content. There are lots of gotchas here, especially about auto-rotation and which window is the keyWindow (which is why you should use #1 or #2 instead if you can).

Answer (score 3):

After some time I was able to get my app working. I have made an easy to use overlay that shows touch feedback over your existing application.

You can download the project here:
https://github.com/megaplow/FingerTracks/tree/master/FingerTracks

[image: Sample Image]

Happy coding,
Joe